# Creating onChangeListener for inflated RadioGroup

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-inflater

I created a `RadioGroup` layout in XML. So I creating it dynamically:

```java
RadioGroup segmentRadioGroup = new RadioGroup(parentActivity);
inflater.inflate(R.layout.segm_btn_stores, segmentRadioGroup);           
segmentRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
            showMap();
        }
    });
```

Oh, it doesn't work! `showMap` is not firing!

But... wait. What if we do it this way?

```java
RadioGroup segmentRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.segm_btn_stores, null);
```

It... works. Why? `segmentRadioGroup` is `RadioGroup` in both cases. And if I pass `segmentRadioGroup` created before instead of `null` it won't work too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RadioGroup segmentRadioGroup = new RadioGroup(parentActivity);
```

In the above line, you create an 'empty' `RadioGroup`. Then...

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.segm_btn_stores, segmentRadioGroup);
```

...in the above line, you inflate another `RadioGroup` from the layout file and it is then 'added' to the first `RadioGroup`. The logic here seems to be that as `RadioGroup` extends (and effectively IS) `LinearLayout`, it is legal for a `RadioGroup` to contain another `RadioGroup`.

```
segmentRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() { ...});
```

Finally, on the line above, you set the listener on the outer / parent `RadioGroup` and not on the inner `RadioGroup`. As such, the `onCheckedChanged(...)` method is never called for the inner `RadioGroup`.

Well that's the only logic I can come up with.

With your second approach...

```
RadioGroup segmentRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.segm_btn_stores, null);
```

You are simply inflating one `RadioGroup` without an outer parent layout because you pass 'null' as the second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
RadioGroup segmentRadioGroup = inflater.inflate(R.layout.segm_btn_stores, null);           
segmentRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(
      new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
                showMap();
            }
      });
// add to the parent layout here..
```